# Define a term in a sentence that is not the primary subject

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have a sentence that includes a term that is being defined (`Euclidean distance`) but is not the primary subject of the sentence:

```
<p>Based on the Euclidean distance (the "ordinary" straight-line distance 
between two points in Euclidean space) formula, the distance between the two 
points is 5.</p>
```

I was thinking of using `<dfn>Euclidean distance</dfn>` but my understanding is that `<dfn>` cannot be used in this sentence because it is not the main subject of/topic in the sentence.

What would be the appropriate markup?

Comment: Well, it IS the main *definition* of the sentence, so that might count.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<dfn>` tag here as that is the defining instance of the sentence. The only caveat here is that you're also providing an additional bit of information to use as an example.

This is acceptable:

```
<p>Based on the <dfn>Euclidean distance</dfn> (the "ordinary" straight-line distance 
between two points in Euclidean space) formula, the distance between the two 
points is 5.</p>
```

Based on the Euclidean distance (the "ordinary" straight-line distance 
between two points in Euclidean space) formula, the distance between the two 
points is 5.

w3schools on the [`dfn` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dfn.asp):

> The  tag represents the defining instance of a term in HTML.
>
> The defining instance is often the first use of a term in a document.
>
> The nearest parent of the  tag must also contain the
>   definition/explanation for the term inside .

1. You're defining the term used.
2. I'm assuming this is the first usage as you're explaining it.
3. It contains an explanation directly after the phrase.

This is fine.

Comment: Note that w3schools is just a third-party source, they have nothing to do with the W3C.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but as a reputable source it's a valid reference.